# Do I need to include the lib file in my final release when building an EXE and a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I understand that the `*.lib` file is used by the linker to map the DLL entry points for the executable. However, once my executable (`*.exe`) has been built, does the lib file need to be included in my installer for the customer?

Comment: It is just for the linker's benefit.  So no.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. You just need the DLL.